# Why rails join on througth relation for foo_ids method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, join

I have relation has_many - has_many like :

```
class baz < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :foo
    has_many :bar, through: :foo
end

class foo < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :baz
   belongs_to :bar
end

class bar < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :foo
   has_many :baz, through: :foo
end
```

if I do `Baz.first.bar_ids`, rails join on bar table instead of get bar_id in foo table... Why? It's useless jointer

SQL log :

```
 SELECT `bar`.id FROM `bar` INNER JOIN `foo` ON `bar`.`id` = `foo`.`bar_id` WHERE `foo`.`baz_id` = 1
```

expected :

```
 SELECT [DISTINCT] `foo`.bar_id FROM `foo` WHERE `foo`.`baz_id` = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expected result will return the `bar_ids` existed in the `foo` table , if you deleted a row from the `bar` table you will always get the his id in return.

Rails expect the element that you looking for exists in the table.

**Edit**

To change this behavior you can do add `bar_ids` method to a `Baz` class

```
class Baz < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :foo
     has_many :bar, through: :foo 

     def bar_ids
        Foo.uniq.pluck(:bar_id).where(baz_id: self.id)
     end 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

you should set up a `has_many :through` relationship if you need to setup the relationship model as an independent entity. You should use `has_many :through` if you need validations, callbacks, or extra attributes on the join model. The corresponding example will be below

```
class baz < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :foo
    has_many :bar, through: :foo
end

class foo < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :baz
   belongs_to :bar
end

class bar < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :foo
   has_many :baz, through: :foo
end
```

The result should be something like this:

```
# baz = Baz.first
# bar = Bar.first

# baz.foo.create(bar: bar)

# baz.bars #= [bar]
```

Comment: it will be `through: :foo` not `trought: :foo`. Please fix the typo.

Comment: It was, its a mistake in message here, but in code I use through^^